# Laravel Mix not loading resources

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to set up Laravel mix to load the js and CSS files. However, they do not load, and it's because the URL is wrong when I checked the page source. The application is deployed on a server. I tried these methods mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247799/laravel-mix-url-processing-works-wrong-when-web-site-on-localhost-is-not-in-ro), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247799/laravel-mix-url-processing-works-wrong-when-web-site-on-localhost-is-not-in-ro), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017024/rendered-fonts-have-wrong-url-laravel-mix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095731/laravel-mix-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-loading). Bit couldn't get it to work. It seems that the changes i make to webpack.mix.js `mix.setResourceRoot("")` has no effect. Could you please help solve this?

**test.blade.php**

```
<link href="{{ asset(mix('/assets/admin/css/laraspace.css')) }}" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix.setPublicPath(path.normalize('public'));
mix.setResourceRoot("")

var pluginPath = 'resources/plugins/'

mix.combine([
    // ** Required Plugins **
    pluginPath + 'jquery/jquery.js',
    pluginPath + 'bootstrap/popper.js',
    pluginPath + 'bootstrap/bootstrap.js',
    pluginPath + 'customScrollBar/customScrollBar.js',

], 'public/assets/admin/js/core/plugins.js')

    .js('resources/admin/js/app.js', 'public/assets/admin/js/core/')

    .sass('resources/admin/sass/laraspace.scss', 'public/assets/admin/css/')

    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    })

    .version();
```

Resource URL in the final HTML document in the browser.

```
<link href="/assets/admin/css/laraspace.css?id=96eccca9789d64d92269" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
```

but it should be

```
<link href="http://example.com/app/assets/admin/css/laraspace.css?id=96eccca9789d64d92269" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
```